# In my sas program i only want data down from my mainframe server where date=20150427

Tags: sas, where-clause

**I want to ask my mainframe server if i only could get the data from the date=20150427. Like a where statement in SQL**

So problem is that the data is "flat" data so i have defined each column with a input statement
i tried to use `where=(L7DANDAT=20150427)` L7DANDAT is the date but it does not work. Hope you guys can help.
CODE:

```
filename DG121'G41066.PUREX.HK000.WAB.HTB.DG121'; 





DATA WAB (compress=binary);


INFILE DG121 ;


INPUT
@   1   LAENGDE ?? IB2.
@   3   TOTANM  ?? IB2.
@   5   REXHTYP ?? IB2.
@   7   RMODTAFD ?? PD3.    
@   10  RANVDATO ?? PD5.
@   15  RKUNDENR ?? PD6.
@   21  RBRKODE ??  PD2.
@   23  RRAADGIV ?? ÅCHAR1.
@   24  RKUNDKAT ?? ÅCHAR3.
@   27  RMAXOPR ??  PD8.2
@   35  RLOBTIDO ?? PD2.
@   37  RPRODBET ?? ÅCHAR6.
@   43  RMEDIE ??   ÅCHAR5.
@   48  ROPSIG ??   ZD3.
@   51  RINDUDL ??  ÅCHAR1.
@   52  RKUNDGRP ?? ÅCHAR1.
@   53  L7HTYP ??   IB2.
@   55  L7TRGRP ??  IB2.
@   57  L7TRART ??  IB2.
@   59  L7TRTYP ??  IB2.
@   61  L7ANSAFD ?? IB2.
@   63  FILLER ??   ÅCHAR2.
@   65  L7TRMIS ??  IB4.
@   69  L7FBRID ??  IB4.
@   73  L7DANDAT ?? IB4.
@   77  L7DANTID ?? IB4.
@   81  L7FANDAT ?? IB4.
@   85  L7FSYST ??  ÅCHAR8.
@   93  L7ARKIV ??  IB8.
@   101 BHTYP ??    PD2.
@   103 BTILBAGE ?? PD1.
@   104 BAUTOMAT ?? PD1.
@   105 BGEBKAT ??  PD2.
@   107 BGEBSTED ?? PD2.
@   109 BPOSART ??  PD2.
@   111 BFOROMR ??  PD2.
@   113 BSFORM ??   PD2.
@   115 BSERVART ?? PD2.
@   117 BFRASTED ?? PD6.
@   123 KTONR   ?? PD6.
@   129 IKSAFDNR    ??  PD3.
@   132 IKSARTNR    ??  PD4.
@   136 FILLER  ??  ÅCHAR3.

;

where=(L7DANDAT=20150427)

;
run;

PROC DOWNLOAD data=WAB  out=WAB V6TRANSPORT EXTENDSN=YES ;RUN;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` statement is allowed in the datastep, but only works on a `SET` statement.  You can't use it on an infile-sourced data step.  You can either:

- Use an IF statement in the data step.
- Use a [WHERE statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000365262.htm) in PROC DOWNLOAD

The former is probably more efficient, but the latter can be better if you're going to repeatedly download different days over time from the same input file.

Comment: i need it for repeatedly download so you recommend it is best to use where statement in proc download like:
PROC DOWNLOAD data=WAB where L7DANDAT=20150427  out=WAB V6TRANSPORT EXTENDSN=YES ?

Comment: WHERE is a statement in the proc, so `proc download <options>; where l7dandate=20150427; run;` or something like that.  So the infile input is executed on the server once (your code above doesn't really show that, so I assume that you're doing that) and you then download it repeatedly as needed.